# Jquery return [object htmlinputelement]

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi i have stuck with the ajax return success. Firstly let me explain what i going to do. 
i have a input form, the form have 3 field text.
1) start Date
2) end Date
3) quarter

the "quarter" field is a drop down list. i have a database to store the date of period of Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4. 
so i want to have, when a user select a drop down, the date will return the Q1 Period.

For now, i'am able to return the result like this:
[{"qstartDate":"11/1/2014","qendDate":"1/31/2014"}]

But, when i wanted to return the date into my form, it fail.
So, Here is my Code.

```
    $("#slc-quarter").change(function () {
    var quarter = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "searchQuarterDetails.asp?term=" + quarter,
        success: function (data) {
                var a = qstartDate;
                alert(a)
            }
        //$("#qstartDate").val(ui.item.qstartDate);
        //$("#qendDate").val(ui.item.qendDate);
    })
})
```

the result that i get from this code after i change the drop down menu is:
[object htmlinputelement]

Comment: instead of putting alert just keep `console.log(a)` and check in `console` what you are getting?

Comment: ` [object htmlinputelement]` is the stringified object returned. You are better off in Chrome/Firefox/IE10+ to run `console.log(a)` to inspect the object. You can also inspect the datapacket using fiddler if you are stuck with an earlier version of IE.

Comment: You don't have a variable named `qstartDate`, so instead you get `window.qstartDate`, which is the element with the ID `qstartDate`, as elements are attatched to the global object by ID.